# pass a PHP object to an ajax PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, json, oop, serialization

How can I pass a PHP object created during my initial page load, to an ajax call?

`create-page.php` creates my page and has an object `expensiveObject`. I need to pass `expensiveObject` to `ajax-some-stuff.php`.

Option 1: Should I json_encode() the object, attach it to my URL, grab that part of my URL with javascript, and send it back to a PHP ajax?

Option 2: Can I store it as a $_SESSION variable?

Comment: If it's a stdClass/anonymous object you can do either if it's a custom class object your better off storing it in a session, just make sure you require the file implementing the class prior to session start, or have an autoloader in play.

Comment: @MartyWallace - in my ajax script, I have some methods that I need the expensive object for `$expensiveObject->someFunction()`.

Comment: I see what you mean now. You don't intend to pass it to the script, you just need reference to it when the script is executed.

Comment: @Orangepill thanks - what is meant by a custom class vs a standard class?

Comment: stdClass object are anonymous objects create by some primative means by php, json_decode without true for the second argument is one of the most common culprits. It will have properties but won't have any methods defined. Custom classes are ones that have an actual class definition associated with them. If you wrote the class that is what I'm referring to as a custom class.

Comment: Yes you can store it in a session variable. What does this object contain? By REST services and SPA client you have to store only the permissions, the token, the user id and the expiration time in the sessions... You can store everything else in the client...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save it in `$_SESSION` as this would prevent you from sending data trough internet which should be only processed on server. There would be security issues as well as performance issues.

You might need to implement `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` depending on your object when saving it in `$_SESSION`

Comment: +1 good point about the wire performance and security issues when you send down to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would like go with Option 1 but after json_encode function i will wrap it again with base64_encode because the json_encode is still not URL-safe string.

The $_SESSION method is good and easy but it depends on your object. If i'm not mistaken, the $_SESSION has maximum size of data can be stored there.
- if you're server side session your server memory will consumed
- using cookie as session replacement will limit the data size

Comment: I thought URLs had similar size restrictions. Most browsers can only handle URLs up to rougly 2000 characters through GET and POST requests I think... Base64, json encoded string might become pretty long